# Inserting variables into arrays

Tags: ruby

I want to generate text and insert them into an array. Please help.

```
new_vrms = Array.new[3] {"placeholder"}
puts "How many registration marks do you require?"
        how_many = gets.chomp!()
        i = 0
        while i < how_many.to_i do
                prefix =('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle.first(2).join
                year = 68
                suffix =('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle.first(3).join
                aVRM = (prefix.to_s + year.to_s + suffix.to_s)
                aVRM = aVRM.upcase!
                puts ("#{aVRM} added to index #{i}")
                #new_vrms.insert(0, 1)  <-Array.rb:14:in `<main>': undefined method `insert' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
                #new_vrms.push << @aVRM  <-Array.rb:15:in `<main>': undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
                #new_vrms[i] = ("#{aVRM}")  <- Array.rb:16:in `<main>': undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
                i += 1
        end         
        puts ("Succesfully generated "+ i.to_s + " registration marks")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is in the array initialization. What you have there (`Array.new[3]`) is seen by ruby as

```
(Array.new)[3]
```

You want to pass 3 to `new` as an argument.

```
Array.new(3)
```

Comment: Nitpicking: it’s seen as `Array.new().[](3)` actually :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: correct. But impossible to read/decipher for a beginner :)

Comment: Even easier to decipher: [3]

Comment: @moveson: that's not what happens here

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended comment about the OPs code in general, so no upvotes please (downvotes are OK).

You begin with

```
new_vrms = Array.new[3] {"placeholder"}
```

@Sergio has identified your problem here, but beyond that there is no need to initialize the value of each element of the array ("placeholder") or even fix the size of the array. Indeed, you evidently wish to return the array with `how_many` elements and `how_many` is not yet know. Therefore, you should simply create an empty array here:

```
new_vrms = Array.new(0)
```

which is the same as

```
new_vrms = Array.new
```

which is more commonly written

```
new_vrms = []
```

Next you ask the user how many elements should be in the array:

```
how_many = gets.chomp!()
```

If the user enters `"3"`, `gets` will return `"3\n"` and `gets.chomp` will return `"3"`. Notice there is no need to end a method (here `chomp`) with `()` when it has no arguments. Also, `chomp!` is not incorrect but the non-mutating version, `chomp`, is generally used. You want `how_many` to be an integer, however, not a string (`gets` always returns a string). You therefore need to convert it to an integer:

```
how_many = gets.chomp.to_i
```

If you look at the doc for [String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-to_i), however, you will see that `"123abc".to_i #=> 123`, so `"123\n".to_i #=> 123`, meaning that we don't need `chomp` when converting a string to an integer:

```
how_any = gets.to_i
```

We now know the number of times we wish to repeat the loop (`how_many`), so you will want to use an iterator and block rather than a `while` loop:

```
how_many.times do |i|
  ...<your code to add elements to new_vrms>
end
new_vrms  # return the computed value
```

See [Integer#times](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-times).

You are repeating code in calculating `prefix` and `suffix`, so let's make that a separate method:

```
LETTERS = ('A'..'Z').to_a 
  #=> ["A", "B", "C",...,"X", "Y", "Z"] 

def random_3_letters
  LETTERS.sample(3).join
end
```

See [Array#sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-sample), which provides a more direct way of computing the random triples of letters. (Also, we may draw from an array of uppercase letters so we don't need to convert the samples to uppercase later.<sup>1</sup>  I created the constant `LETTERS` so that we don't need to create the array each time the method is called. We can now write the block.

```
YEAR = "68"
how_many.times do |i|
  prefix = random_3_letters
  suffix = random_3_letters
  aVRM = prefix + YEAR + SUFFIX
  puts "#{aVRM} added to index #{i}")
  new_vrms.push(aVRM) 
end
new_vrms
```

There is, in fact, no reason to define the variables `prefix` and `suffix`, as we can simplify as follows.

```
YEAR = "68"
how_many.times do |i| 
  aVRM = random_3_letters + YEAR + random_3_letters
  puts "#{aVRM} added to index #{i}")
  new_vrms.push(aVRM) 
end
new_vrms
```

If you wish to print the value of each element of `aVRM` it's best to do that from outside the loop--more generally from outside a method you will wrap around the code. If the statement `puts "#{aVRM} added to index #{i}")` is extracted from the block the block variable `i` is no longer used, so it can be omitted:

```
YEAR = "68"

def doit
  new_vrms = []
  gets.to_i.times do 
    new_vrms << random_3_letters + YEAR + random_3_letters
  end
  new_vrms 
end
```

Notice that I've changed [Array#push](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-push) to the more-commonly used Array#<< and substituted out the variables `how_many` and `aVRS`.

An experienced Rubyist might tighten this up even more (though input values would also be checked for validity in real code):

```
LETTERS = ('A'..'Z').to_a 
YEAR = "68"

def doit
  gets.to_i.times.with_object([]) do |_,new_vrms|
    new_vrms << (random_3_letters + YEAR + random_3_letters)
  end
end

def random_3_letters
  LETTERS.sample(3).join
end

doit  # entering "4"
  #=> ["ZPI68LWY", "PQV68HLD", "IZG68JCH", "EAC68WLY"]
```

Notice that by using [Enumerator#with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) we eliminate the statement `new_vrms = []` and `new_vrms` at the end, the latter because `with_object` causes the block to return the "object", the value of `new_vrms`.

<sup>1 Note that you should never write `str = str.upcase!` because `str.upcase!` returns `nil` if `str` is already upcased (and therefore no changes are made to `str`). See [String#upcase!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-upcase-21). Many "bang" methods `...!` return `nil` when no change is made to the receiver.</sup>